# Use a state variable inside a method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

For example this code:

```
export const Test = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  let number;

  const DivideByCounter = () => {
     number = 10 / counter;
  }

  const IncreaseCounter = () => {
      for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         setCounter(counter + i);
  }
}
```

It's just an example of a code that I'm working on. The problem here is that the setCounter is updating the state correctly, however, when I use the counter to divide, it's returning me Infinity. When I console.log(counter) it's showing me 0, the initial state, however, outside the function, it shows me the updated state. Does everybody know how can I pass the update state into the function so it won't return me Infinity? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How are you calling `DivideByCounter`, is it possible you are doing so before the state has finished updating? (As setting state is asynchronous)

Comment: use useCallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be connected to the fact that you call `DivideByCounter` before `counter` will be updated. Just add a check in `DivideByCounter` that, if `counter === 0` then `number = 0`. Something like:

```
export const Test = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  let number;

  const DivideByCounter = () => {
     if (counter === 0) number = 0;
     else number = 10 / counter;
  }

  const IncreaseCounter = () => {
      for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         setCounter(counter + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: The check has worked, now I will try to add to useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You're initial value is set to zero so when you divide for the first time you are dividing by zero which gives infinity

Maybe try adding an exception for zero like the other answer and add a useEffect containing the Divide by counter code and add counter as a dependency

Comment: I'm using the useEffect, however with no dependencies. The exception worked, now it's returning me the value that it's expected, I will try adding counter as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components, in simple words, it means, it lets you run code when state changes or when a prop changes.

you can use `UseEffect` to update `number` only when there is a change to your counter, or a change to another prop that you want.

```html
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  let number;

  useEffect(() => {
    DivideByCounter();
    console.log(number);
  }, [counter]);

  const DivideByCounter = () => {
    number = 10 / counter;
  };

  const IncreaseCounter = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      setCounter(counter + i);
    }
  };
```

you can share how did you try to call `DivideByCounter`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but in `IncreaseCounter` first for iteration sets counter to 0 and in that case `DivideByCounter` sets number to Infinity again... Right?